# How to get a DocumentSnapshot to query by document ID

Tags: flutter, google-cloud-firestore

I have to query a collection to find a document by documentID just created, but I need to get and pass the DocumentSnapshot instead of a DocumentReference. How can I get it?
I have this

```
   if (_pfKey.currentState.validate()) {
      _pfKey.currentState.save();
      String ragsoc = _cognome + " " + _nome;
     //   DocumentReference ds =Firestore.instance.collection('pazienti').document(this.record);

      for (i = 0; i < ragsoc.length; i++) {
        indici.add(ragsoc.substring(0, i + 1).toLowerCase());
      }
      Map<String, dynamic> miorecord = {
        "nome": _nome,
        "cognome": _cognome,
        "datanascita": _datanascita,
        "luogonascita": _luogonascita,
        "codicefiscale": _codfisc,
        "cap": _cap,
        "provincia": _provincia,
        "indirizzo": _indirizzo,
        "citta": _citta,
        "ciclo": _ciclo,
        "figli": _figli,
        "patologiemam": _patomamm,
        "tormonale": _tormonale,
        "searchIndex": indici
      };


     DocumentReference ds =  await Firestore.instance.collection('pazienti').add(miorecord).catchError((e) {
        print(e);
      }); 

       DocumentSnapshot documentSnapshot = ds.firestore.collection('pazienti').document(ds.documentID);
```

Thank you :/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try Saving data using your own customId
and retrieve using that id.

Try this:-

```
Firestore _fireStore = Firestore.instance;


await _fireStore
      .collection('fireStoreCollectionName')
      .document('customId')
      .setData(miorecord);

DocumentSnapshot documentSnapshot = await _fireStore
      .collection('fireStoreCollectionName')
      .document('customId')
      .get();

Map mapName = documentSnapshot.data;
```

Comment: Thank you. I was just missing the await and .get();